# Java-toUpperCase a letter

Tags: java, indexof

Enter a line of text. No punctuation please.

Java is the language.

I have rephrased that line to read:

Is the language java.

Attempt:

```
 int x;
 String  sentence, first;

 System.out.println("\nEnter a line of text. No punctuation please.");

 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

 sentence=keyboard.nextLine();

   x = sentence.indexOf(" ");
 first= sentence.substring(0,x);
 second=sentence.substring(0,1)
 second=second.toUpperCase();  
 System.out.println("I have rephrased that line to read:");
 System.out.println(second+sentence.substring(x+1)+" "+first);
```

Output:

Enter a line of text. No punctuation please.

what is going on

I have rephrased that line to read:// It should read " Is going on what"

W s going on what

P.S -I need to make letter "i" capital. How can I make "second.substring(0,1)" read character "i"? As suggested, I tried to figure out the stripping the letter and concatenating it with the uppercase but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The "i" would be

```
second=sentence.substring(x+1,x+2);
```

In other words, the character after the space.  You're currently taking the first character in the input string.

Comment: @jay: If you feel this answered your question, please consider accepting the answer (using the checkmark next to the answer).  This marks the question as answered.